# Substring extraction from a given string, Oracle

Tags: oracle, substring

I need to extract a string from a given set of string. The string given is :

```
Data string 1 : LOAD TEST ABC,2146520,9856452147
Data string 2 : LOAD TEST:804749:9756325874
```

Here, the string set has a static value "LOAD TEST ABC" and "LOAD TEST", here i need to extract the string from the middle 2146520 and 804749 as an Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here with a capture group:

```
SELECT col, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '[,:](.+?)[,:]', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS middle_num
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo